# Leetcode Rearrange Products Table Medium Level

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image: Input and Output]

I saw one answer in discussion as below

```
SELECT A.product_id, B.COLUMN_NAME as store,
CASE
    WHEN B.COLUMN_NAME = "store1" THEN store1
    WHEN B.COLUMN_NAME = "store2" THEN store2
    WHEN B.COLUMN_NAME = "store3" THEN store3
END AS price
FROM Products A, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B
  WHERE table_name = 'Products' AND column_name != "product_id"
  HAVING price IS NOT NULL
```

Can someone please explain how can we write this INFORMATION_SCHEMA and could still get the output. This is in MYSQL

Comment: Why `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`? You just need to write a UNION query to do this on the `products` table. `SELECT product_id, 'store1' as store, store1 as price from products UNION ALL SELECT product_id, 'store2' as store, store2 as price from products UNION ALL SELECT product_id, 'store3' as store, store3 as price from products;` No reason to get fancy. You may need a `WHERE store1/2/3 IS NOT NULL` at the end of each of those depending on how picky it is.

Comment: Hi @JNevill,

Even I know the answer for Union but one person wrote this query in complete different way as I pasted in the above. Under his response everyone's comment is how did he do that. So , I want to know how did he solve that in that way. Please let me know if you can make me understand that query

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of techniques are used to pull this off:

1. Cross Join: Instead of joining the two tables on a key, instead the OOP is joining every record of `Products` with every records of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` (where the column_name isn't `product_id`). Essentially they are making an intermediate result set that looks like:

   ```
    +------------+--------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
    | product_id | store1 | store2 | store3 | table_name | column_name |
    +------------+--------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
    |          0 |     95 |    100 |    105 | Products   | store3      |
    |          0 |     95 |    100 |    105 | Products   | store2      |
    |          0 |     95 |    100 |    105 | Products   | store1      |
    |          1 |     70 |        |     80 | Products   | store3      |
    |          1 |     70 |        |     80 | Products   | store2      |
    |          1 |     70 |        |     80 | Products   | store1      |
    +------------+--------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
   ```

You can see each row of `products` is triplicated as there are three rows of column metadata in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

2. A Case Expression to generate a new column on this intermediate result set that pulls the correct `store` column's int value based on the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.column_name` for that row:

   ```
   SELECT A.*, B.COLUMN_NAME as store,
   CASE
       WHEN B.COLUMN_NAME = "store1" THEN store1
       WHEN B.COLUMN_NAME = "store2" THEN store2
       WHEN B.COLUMN_NAME = "store3" THEN store3
   END AS price
   FROM Products A, INFO_SCHEMA B
   WHERE table_name = 'Products' AND column_name != "product_id"
   HAVING price IS NOT NULL;

   +------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
   | product_id | store1 | store2 | store3 | store  | price |
   +------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
   |          0 |     95 |    100 |    105 | store3 |   105 |
   |          0 |     95 |    100 |    105 | store2 |   100 |
   |          0 |     95 |    100 |    105 | store1 |    95 |
   |          1 |     70 |        |     80 | store3 |    80 |
   |          1 |     70 |        |     80 | store1 |    70 |
   +------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
   ```

I included the original columns from `Products` table to show what the case expression is doing.

3. The sneaky `HAVING` clause tossed on at the end. Because the `price` columns derived by the case expression doesn't exist at the point of query execution when the `WHERE` clause is executed, OOP snuck in this `HAVING` clause which evaluates near the end of the sql execution steps when the `price` column was made into existence. The reason I say it's sneaky is because `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY` or any aggregation at all is an oddball and may fail in other RDBMS (but I'd have to test).